# Posting to action, mvc 3, not part of form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, forms, post

Can I post to action from view a filed of of my model ? Is is not part of the form. I just want to pass the myModel.someValue as argument to nextRelease action, hopefully without putting it anywhere in the form.

e.g.

View:

```
@model myModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "News", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "myform" }))
{
<div>myModel.someValue</div> //to show it has this field

<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#nextbutton').click(function () {
        $('#myform').attr("action", "/@controller.Language/news/nextRelease");
        $("#submit").click();
   });
</script>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you could use AJAX:

```
@model myModel

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#nextbutton').click(function () {
            var url = '@Url.Action("NextRelease", "News")';
            var dataToPost = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(new { someValue = Model.SomeValue }));
            $.post(url, dataToPost, function(result) {
                alert('data successfully posted to server');
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<button id="nextbutton">Next button</button>
```

or if you wanted to post not only a single property but the entire model:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("NextRelease", "News")';
var dataToPost = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(dataToPost),
    success: function(result) {
        alert('data successfully posted to server');
    }
});
```